# How to configure Cloudwatch Alarms - check for 5 errors once every 30 minutes

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloudwatch-alarms

Can someone please explain how i should configure my cloudwatch alarms as the documentation is terribly confusing.

Use case: I want to check for errors once every 30 mins and trigger an alarm if i see more than 5 errors in the logs.

```
Below is my current configuration:
threshold - 5
period - 1800
datapoints_to_alarm - 1
evaluation_periods - 1
comparison_operator - GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold
statistic - Sum
treat_missing_data- notBreaching
```

When i tested with period as 120 i was able to validate that the alarm gets triggered when there are 5 or more errors in the logs.

However, when i changed the period to 1800 i am seeing that the alarm is triggered instantly on seeing 5 erros in the logs and its not coming out of alarm state for 1800sec(30 mins). Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: The threshold refers to the metric units and not data points. When you set the period at 1800 seconds, it means a point is evaluated every 30 minutes. Since you have 1 for data points and evaluation period, it means that one evaluation is enough to go into and out of the alarm. Every data point the alarm checks if the units of the metric are above the threshold.

Comment: @kgiannakakis so what should i set the value as, sorry i am still confused on this?

Comment: What your period should be? This is the quickest an alarm can change state.

Comment: @kgiannakakis the basic use case is to trigger the alarm if we see 5 errors in the logs, i want to check this once every 30 mins. Struggling to set the right values for all params in there

Comment: Then it seems to me that you have it right. Every 30 minutes, if there are more 5 errors, the alarm will go into alarm state. In next point, if there are less than 5 errors, it will go to OK. What isn't working?

Comment: @kgiannakakis i am trying to make it come out of the error state before that 30 mins, so it can recheck. Although, this defies my original question :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240361/discussion-between-kgiannakakis-and-contraboy).

Comment: @kgiannakakis thanks for all your help on this and clarifying my doubts!

Answer (score 0):

The above solution is the answer to the question. There is no way to get out of the alarm state before the defined period, evaluation_period ends.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).